# System.EngineExecutionException on a return from a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, .net-3.5

This one has us all baffled at work. We have two services running on .net 3.5 SP1 that hits up sharepoint, and return Lists of model objects that are pretty similar. One of them works fine, the other throws an EngineExecutionException on the return.

I know that is sort of vague, but everything executes fine right up until that point. When you look at the List in the debugger, everything looks pretty normal.

Has anyone had this happen before? If so, what did you do to work around it?

Comment: This is one of the strangest exceptions in .NET it seems. I get one too in an ASP.NET MVC3 app on a contract assertion (code contracts)

Comment: @Andrei: that exception is basically a low level framework crash. Usuallly you only see them with pretty new stuff (like wcf back when i posted it, or mvc 3)

Comment: Yeah... I guess the Code Contracts are a bit too new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that if you have ILists in your data contract, the framework blows up. Change IList to List as your return type, and it works